# "sudo" commands is not requiring a password on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 Amazon EC2 instance.

The only user in the instance is `ubuntu`

I have successfully SSH in my new instance and works fine.

I can run `sudo` commands like so:

`sudo apt-get update`

However I am concerned at the fact that sudo does not ask for any passwords.

I figured this is because there is no password for my default `ubuntu` account.

So I typed in the following command:

```
$ passwd
(current) UNIX password:
```

I left the 2nd field blank and click Enter and it gave me the following message:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

I then decided to do:

$ sudo passwd

This allowed me to change my password, but whenever I do any sudo commands, it does not seem to work.

How can I set it so `sudo` requires a password?

Also what did `sudo passwd` do exactly and how can I undo it?

Comment: For security reasons, I would recommend disabling any user with sudo permissions that is on the machine by default and I would create a new user with a different name. Anyone with sudo privileges should have a password. As for the machine not prompting you for a password, remember that once you enter your password for one sudo command, the machine "remembers" that you just entered it for some period of time and won't prompt you until some time has elapsed. You may find [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37299/how-does-sudo-remember-you-already-entered-roots-password) helpful.

Comment: @S.Imp The thing is that I NEVER entered a password, so it's not a time elapse issue.

Comment: If I understand your post, sudo did not require you to enter a password first time--the user had no password. Perhaps sudo isn't smart enough to realize that you have changed the user's password -- it just "remembered" that a few seconds before you successfully authenticated to have sudo privileges. If you change the user to have a password then logout and log back in again and it STILL doesn't require you to enter a password, the issue may be in the [sudoers configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos).

Comment: @S.Imp I logged out and logged back in and still doesn't ask for a password. The issue is that `ubuntu` doesn't have a password, but I can't seem to change it as it asks me for the current password. However there is no current password.

Comment: Like I said, you should create a new user, e.g., **yahya**, who DOES have a password and grant sudoer privileges to that user then disable the ubuntu user -- and make sure the sudoer config requires that user to enter their password.

Comment: Is it not possible to just add a password to the ubuntu user?

Comment: You clearly said in your post that you successfully changed the password for user **ubuntu**. I assume that means you must provide that password when you login to the machine (or perhaps you're using a key pair?). If your machine never prompts the ubuntu user for a password when it runs sudo commands, that's probably due to the sudoers configuration file. I provided a link above that should be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer my own question...

The default ubuntu user password is locked. Therefore to change it you need to do the following:

```
$ sudo passwd ubuntu
```

To undo changing the root password and re-lock it (as it was before) do the following:

```
$ sudo passwd root -l
```

To make sure sudo asks for your password each time you use sudo on the `ubuntu` default user, run the following command (NOTE: You need to have a password set for ubuntu or you may get locked out of sudo):

```
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users
```

And comment out the line with ubuntu like so:

```
# ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

or change to:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

The following helped:

https://serverfault.com/questions/615034/disable-nopasswd-sudo-access-for-ubuntu-user-on-an-ec2-instance/684504#684504

Comment: Side note: Ubuntu Server 20.04 for Raspberry (arm64) works in a very similar way: `ubuntu` is a sudoer that requires no password, but password is not locked (`ubuntu` by default, set to force change upon first login)